# Using asp.net 4.5 OAuth to register google with clientid and secret

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I notice in the asp.net 4.5 template, all the authorization samples besides google pass in secret and clientid.  How can I pass in my google secret and clientid?  Brock has a good discussion here that I'm following:

http://info.develop.com/blogs/bid/232864/ASP-NET-Using-OAuthWebSecurity-without-SimpleMembership#.UNuBh2_Adv9

The sample code is as follows that comes with the template.

```
internal static class AuthConfig
{
    public static void RegisterOpenAuth()
    {
        // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252803 for details on setting up this ASP.NET
        // application to support logging in via external services.

        //OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddTwitter(
        //    consumerKey: "your Twitter consumer key",
        //    consumerSecret: "your Twitter consumer secret");

        //OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddFacebook(
        //    appId: "your Facebook app id",
        //    appSecret: "your Facebook app secret");

        //OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddMicrosoft(
        //    clientId: "your Microsoft account client id",
        //    clientSecret: "your Microsoft account client secret");

       // OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass in the app id and secret? It will let your users authenticate and let you get their data without it.

Comment: Hi Jed,  I need the appId and secret so I can store the token and pass the token to a client app to use for authentication.

Comment: Also, I need the token to authenticate my IMAP client with google. That is my primary objective for using OAuth here.

Comment: I see lots of people have viewed and no one has answered. I'm wondering if this means that oauth in asp.net has no way of getting token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth/OAuthWebSecurity.cs) of the [`OAuthWebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.webpages.oauth.oauthwebsecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class.

The reason Google's authentication client doesn't need an AppId/AppSecret is because its implementation is using **[OpenId](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)** and **NOT [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)**.

If you want to use OAuth with Google you'll have to write your own client (at least for right now).