# Application name on requesting login using oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, oauth-2.0

My ASP.NET MVC has login with Google, Facebook and Microsoft. It works fine. But when the user tries to login with gmail, the next message is shown in the google login page:

`IP_ADDRESS_SERVER is asking for some information from your Google Account. To see and approve the request, sign in. Learn more`

Instead of showing the ip address, I would like to show the application name or the domain, something like:

`MyWebApplication is asking for some information from your Google Account. To see and approve the request, sign in. Learn more`

or

`www.mywebsite.com is asking for some information from your Google Account. To see and approve the request, sign in. Learn more`

How can I achieve that? Should I change some configuration in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [register the application with Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto).

Comment: Thanks. Now I have registered succesfully my domain but it isn't working yet. I have a `OAuth Consumer Key` and a `OAuth Consumer Secret`. Should I use this in my ASP.NET MVC app? In the `AuthConfig.cs` file?

Comment: It seems that by default, Google use OpenId instead of Oauth (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14551835/1204249). Do you know how can I use Google with Oauth?